# Golang: net/http client nil when calling struct is passed to a go routine

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

Having an interesting issue where the net/http(*Client) pointer, specifically the gcp go sdk compute.Operation package attempts to make a request with a nil http client but only when used in a go routine. Here is an example

```
import (
    compute "cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1"
    computepb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/compute/v1"
)

func WaitForImages(op *compute.Operation, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    op.Wait(ctx)
    // Do some stuff after the image is made
}
func TakeImage(context context.Context, req *computepb.InsertImageRequest, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
     c, err := compute.NewImagesRESTClient(ctx)
     defer c.Close()
     if err != nil {
         return
     }
     op, err := c.Insert(ctx, req)
     if err != nil {
         return
     }
     wg.Add(1)
     go WaitForImages(op, wg)
}

func Main() {
   images := [//List of images]
   var wg *sync.WaitGroup = &sync.WaitGroup{}
   ctx := context.TODO()
   for _, img := range images {
        img := img
        req := &computepb.InsertImageRequest{

            Project:  myProject,

            ImageResource: &computepb.Image{
                Name:       &img,
                SourceDisk: &img,
            },
        }
        TakeImage(ctx, req, wg)
   }
   wg.Wait()
}
```

This is the error I get

```
4  0x00000000006ee4d7 in net/http.(*Client).deadline
         at /usr/lib/go-1.19beta1/src/net/http/client.go:188
     5  0x00000000006f1105 in net/http.(*Client).do
         at /usr/lib/go-1.19beta1/src/net/http/client.go:599
     6  0x00000000006f0f4f in net/http.(*Client).Do
         at /usr/lib/go-1.19beta1/src/net/http/client.go:581
     7  0x00000000006f08a5 in net/http.(*Client).Get
```

This only happens if I do the op.Wait(ctx) inside a go routine. If I just wait for it regularly I get no issue. My actual program is much longer and I don't make it to the end of that program, in fact if I hit "step" on the debugger relatively slowly it panics after just a few lines, but in a full speed run sometimes I can make 2-3 image requests sometimes only 1. I tried turning off the golang garbage collector on the chance it was destroying the http client but had no luck.

Comment: Yes I did thank you, let me edit that

Comment: One issues I see is that you have a data race because you are sharing the **single** (reused by `range`) `img` iteration variable with all your goroutines. Not good. Try `img := img` at the top of the loop to create a copy unique to each iteration.

Comment: This is a common gotcha. The iteration variables or not safe to be used outside of the iteration, they are not safe to be used by closures or child goroutines. You need to create copies of those variables if you want to use them outside of the loop.

Comment: Sorry, this is a recreated snippet of some larger code. The original has this I just missed it. But unfortunately this happens even with only 1 object in the list and I keep the loop alive after, tested it out just now out of curiosity

Comment: Thought this might be related to the image client but even passing that to the go routine and making sure it stays alive doesn't fix anything

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the c.Close() call. Even though gcp returns a new *compute.Operation client it is still reliant on the old *compute.ImagesClient. Calling close before the *compute.Operation.Wait() call causes a nil pointer dereference.